# Is there a way to mount all the files from directory to container directory without deleting its content?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

To be more specific I like to mount configuration files to conf directory in Tomcat 9.
The idea behind this is to let the files to be changed in run time and to save the down&up time of the container.

The idea is to generate container with this dir:

```
/MyTomcat/conf
```

and the docker-compose file will look like:

```
version: '3'
services:
  MyApplication:
    image: enviroment:MyApplication
    volumes:
      - ./path/to/host/dir:/MyTomcat/conf
```

without deleting the existing files

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I 100% understand the use-case, but couldn't you copy the current state of /MyTomcat/conf into ./path/to/host/dir along with any additional files you want to add? Then, you wouldn't need to worry about it replacing files internally and any changes on the host OS or in the container would be reflected in the other location.

Also as a side note, if you want this container to be portable between systems then would recommend you use volumes (https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) instead of a bind-mount if possible. Then, you can COPY the default files there during the Dockerfile build. Otherwise, you can hit permissions/directory structure issues when moving between systems.

Comment: I don't want to copy, I like to generate a symlink